# Make the height of the view dynamically change with height of image Xcode swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uiscrollview, uiimageview

I have an image that I want to take up the entirety of the screen in a UIScrollView. However, to avoid clipping and distortion of the image I have the constraints set so the image will always have the correct aspect ratio. When you run this on different size screens, the image is different sizes. Is there some code I can program in to make my scrollview always the same height as my image? I need my scrollview to change depending on the height of the image since on different devices the height of my image will change.

so far I have:

```
class Second : UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var myScrollView: UIScrollView!
@IBOutlet weak var myImage: UIImageView!

override func viewDidLoad() {

    ScrollView.contentSize.height = 1300

}
```

The constraints I used on the image are:

- Equal width as the scrollview
- entered horizontally in the scrollview
- Top space to the top of the scrollview
- Aspect fit (so the image is not distorted)

Thank you. Any help is very appreciated!

Answer (score -1):

You need following constraint

```
For ScrollView:
```

Leading and top Space To superView

```
For ImageView inside ScrollView :
```

Equal Width and Height to Scrollview
Top , Bottom ,Trail and Leading space to Scrollview

Comment: This will make my image view whatever size my scrollview is but what I want is for my scrollview to dynamically change depending on the height of my image (since it will be different heights on different devices

Comment: We have given equal height constraint so the scrollview takes the images height